# Centralizar DIV com Bootstrap ou CSS

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia,

Vocês poderiam me ajudar? Gostaria de centralizar uma Div(id="novoServico") que é exibida ao Clicar em um Btn(id="novoServicoBtn").

Segue abaixo o código

```html
<?php 
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['User'])){
  
 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ERP.css">

<head>

 <title>ERP Nserv</title>
 <?php require_once "menu.php"; ?>

</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">

   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
     <span class="btn btn-default" id="novoServicoBtn">Cadastrar Novo</span>
     <span class="btn btn-default" id="servicosFeitosBtn">Lista de Serviços</span>
    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="centralizarERP" id="novoServico"></div>
     <div id="servicosFeitos"></div>
    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="row">
   <br>
   <h3 align="center">ENTRADA DE SERVIÇOS</h3>
   <br>
    <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
     <div id="tabelaServicosEntrada"></div>
    </div>

   </div>

 </div>

</body>

</html>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#tabelaServicosEntrada').load('servicos/tabelaServicosEntrada.php');

   $('#novoServicoBtn').click(function(){
    esconderSessao();
    $('#novoServico').load('servicos/cadastrarServico.php');
    $('#novoServico').show();
   });
   $('#servicosFeitosBtn').click(function(){
    esconderSessao();
    $('#servicosFeitos').load('#');
    $('#servicosFeitos').show();
   });
  });

  function esconderSessao(){
   $('#novoServico').hide();
   $('#servicosFeitos').hide();
  }

 </script>

<?php 
 }else{
  header("location:../index.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Essa Div é herdada de uma outra classe, segue abaixo o código:

```html
<?php 

require_once "../../Classes/Conexao.php";

 $c= new conectar();
 $conexao=$c->conexao();
?>

<br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" align="center">
  <form id="frmNovoServico">
   <label>Cliente</label>
   <select class="form-control input-sm" id="clienteSelect" name="clienteSelect">
    <option value="A">Selecionar</option>
    <option value="0">Sem Cliente</option>
    <?php

    $sql="SELECT ID_Cliente, Nome, Sobrenome FROM clientes";

    $result=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

    while ($cliente=mysqli_fetch_row($result)):
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $cliente[0] ?>"><?php echo $cliente[1]." ".$cliente[2] ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
   </select>
   <br>
   <label>Equipamento</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="equipamento" name="equipamento">
   <br>
   <label>Informação</label>
   <textarea type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="informacao" name="informacao" rows="5" />
   <br>
   <label>Número Serial</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="serialnumber" name="serialnumber">
   <p></p>
   <span class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddServico">Cadastrar Serviço</span>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#btnAddServico').click(function(){

    vazios=validarFormVazio('frmNovoServico');

    if(vazios > 0){
     alertify.alert("ATENÇÃO","Preencha todos os Campos");
     return false;
    }

    dados=$('#frmNovoServico').serialize();

    $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     data:dados,
     url:"../Procedimentos/servicos/cadastrarServico.php",
     success:function(r){

      if(r==1){
       $('#frmNovoServico')[0].reset();
       alertify.success("Cadastro com Sucesso");
       $('#tabelaServicosEntrada').load('servicos/tabelaServicosEntrada.php');
      }else{
       alertify.error("Não foi possível Cadastrar");
      }
     }
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Qual versão do bootstrap vc está usando ?

Comment: Versão 4, mas retirei o link da Página. Código acima corrigido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho um ambiente para testar exatamente o seu código, mas aqui está um exemplo simples de como alinha horizontalmente usando Bootstrap 4, basta vc usar a classe `mx-auto` na `col`.

`mx-auto` significa que o elemento tem margem automática no eixo `x`, mas para funcionar vc tem que colocar o form ou os inputs dentro de uma coluna, e seguir o padrão do Grid do Bootstrap, como no exemplo abaixo, nele eu alinhei um `col-3` no centro da `row`. Nem precisa de fazer CSS para esse tipo de alinhamento!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
    <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já testo e te falo, de qualquer forma Obrigado

Comment: Muito Bom, resolveu!

Comment: @NCesar massa! 

Answer (score 0):

Para alinhar a DIV horizontalmente, aplique os seguintes atributos CSS nela

```
#novoServico{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: realmente centralizou, porém os Inputs ficaram pequenos e desajustados. No caso, teria que ajustá-los individual ou existe uma outra forma de corrigir? Obrigado

Comment: coloca width: 100% na row e ve se muda algo

Comment: Não muda, e se eu colocar na própria DIV anula a configuração de Centralização que o Leandro citou.

Comment: Como você está utilizando o bootstrap, seria interessante você fazer esse posicionamento usando as classes "offset" do modelo de grid...
Da uma olhada nesse link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns